# How to show component selector on click event Angular5

Tags: angular5, angular-components, ng-class

I am getting issue while display another component on click event, here is my code:

```
<div (click)="showThis = true"></div>
<div class="" [ngClass]="{'hide': showThis}"></div>
<div class="" [ngClass]="{'show': showThis}">
  <another-screen></another-screen>
    </div>
```

its displaying both, first should display without any click, if click event then this hide first and another component will display

means hide and show class will apply
any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use hidden:

```
<div (click)="showThis = true"></div>
<div class="" [hidden]="!showThis"></div>
<div class="" [hidden]="showThis">
    <another-screen></another-screen>
</div>
```

*ngIf removes the html element from  DOM but `[hidden]` is use for display none or block html element same as hide and show

Comment: @RiteshDoomra don't forgot to accept an answer if this help you

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `*ngIf`

```
<div (click)="showThis = true"></div>
<div *ngIf="!showThis "></div>
<div *ngIf="showThis ">
  <another-screen></another-screen>
</div>
```